# How to use {{{{raw-helper}}}} in a handlebars template

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have a handlebars template that works great. I'd like to be able to put the following in it:

```
<script id="someTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="editStuff">
        <span {{#if aThing}} data-someKey="{{anotherThing}}" {{/if}}>
            {{aThirdThing}}
        </span>
    </div>
</script>
```

This obviously would render when the handlebars file is processed. all of the {{}}'s end up being blank, no good. I found the

```
{{{{raw-helper}}}}
```

block helper, and tried it out like so:

```
{{{{raw-helper}}}}
<script id="someTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="editStuff">
        <span {{#if aThing}} data-addresskey="{{anotherThing}}" {{/if}}>
            {{aThirdThing}}
        </span>
    </div>
</script>
{{{{/raw-helper}}}}
```

but this ends up removing the entire script block from the HTML.

According to the [Handlebars docs](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html#raw-blocks) anything within the raw block should be rendered untouched.

Comment: Just in case this was not a built in helper, I also tried registering the handler in the sample on the docs page. No good. It's pretty difficult to tell what is and isn't baked in on the handlebars API.

Answer (score 7):

The raw-helper is not built in. After you register the template is should work.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('raw', function(options) {
  return options.fn(this);
});

{{{{raw}}}}
<script id="someTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{test}}
</script>
{{{{/raw}}}}
```

Comment: Why is it not built in? Seems silly to mention it in the docs.